# Solving a area problem in a different way gives different solutions

Tags: geometry

today I was confronted with this little area problem from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgrWHOocYZA

So I gave it a try and came up with a solution. But after comparing the solution with the solution from the video mine seems to be wrong. But I can't figure out what the problem in the solving is because it seems to be correct on mathematical perspective.

The concept behind my solution is that I created 3 equations for solving. Those are the 3 equations on the right top corner of the sheet. From there on I just eliminated the variables and got the solution. But with this equations I get to 25.5 cm^2 so what I suspect is that those equations are somehow incorrect.

Can someone explain me why this solution is wrong and if there is a way like mine to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your solution is incorrect because you've essentially redrawn the problem presented by the video such that the lines are nicer and just assumed that the areas are the same, which is not true. The partition of the square presented by the video does not break it up into four rectangles, as you do, and so the area formula of base times height is not directly applicable, and this is the foundation of your equations.

Comment: Hmm but isn't it possible to break up every tetragon into a rectangle so the area is the same? That was my idea behind the given solution

Comment: It's not clear what you're claiming there. While it's true that, given any four areas summing to the total area of a given square, you can decompose the square into a union of rectangles with these areas, there's no reason they would have to be arranged so nicely with respect to each other, as you've drawn in your diagram. In fact, your computations show that, in this case, they *cannot* be arranged so nicely (i.e., they cannot all share a common vertex).